# Lookup dynamic dictionary key

Tags: python

I'm trying to lookup a static value combined with a dynamic variable in a dictionary.

For example, a key in `my_dict` is: `static_value1`

My current code is:

```
dynamic_variable = 1

string = "static_value" + str(dynamic_variable)

my_dict[string]
```

But, with this code `string` is actually: `'static_value1'`

I need it without the quotes to properly look up the dictionary key.

How could I do this? Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to change the string into a variable name before using it as a key. Perhaps this?

```
my_dict[eval(string)]
```

As nneonneo mentioned in his answer, using `eval` with a user supplied string is generally a bad idea, because it represents a security vulnerability, since you have just given your user the ability to execute arbitrary code on your system.

Comment: For sure. :) Have to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of a "dynamic variable" by using the `globals` function:

```
my_dict[globals()[string]]
```

assuming that the variable is in global (module) scope. (If it isn't, use `locals()` instead).

This is faster and safer than using `eval`.

---

In general, you should try to avoid looking variables up dynamically in Python (the exception is when working with functions like `__getattr__`). Instead, consider using a dictionary to store mappings of names to keys. Dictionaries are more convenient than a collection of similarly-named variables in several ways.